# How to throw an exception from onClickListener's methods

Tags: android

I am getting the following error (which I understand) : `Overriden method does not throw ...`

I would like to know how to throw an exception form within View.onClickListener's  `onClick` method (if it is even possible).

Comment: You can always throw unchecked exceptions (`RuntimeException` for example) without needed to declare the throw

Comment: Can you be specific which method are you trying to override?

Comment: @AritraRoy `void onClick(View v)`

Comment: @AritraRoy `which method?`, like, the only method in `OnClickListener`...

Comment: @njzk2 I am throwing a Custom exception. Yup I wrote methods, should have been method :)

Comment: your custom exception is unchecked if it inherits an unchecked exception. `RuntimeException` is the most generic type. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/RuntimeException.html

Comment: @njzk2 -_- Could have guessed that after your first comment ... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot throw a *checked* exception in an overridden method if the initial declaration does not include the `throw` declaration.

You can, however, throw an *unchecked* exception, which is an Exception that the compiler does not check to see if it is handled:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View target) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Or any Exception, built-in or custom, that inherits `RuntimeException`. The list of such built-in exceptions is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can always launch an Exception

```
throw new Exception();
```

You can even implement your own exceptions and get its parameters

```
public class MyOwnException extends Exception {
    private int data;

    public MyOwnException(int data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

...

try {
    throw new MyOwnException(10);
} catch {MyOwnException moe) {
    int i = moe.getData();
    // i = 10;
}
```

Remember that if a method may throw an Exception you must declare it

```
public void sampleMethod throws MyOwnException {
    ...
}
```

Comment: the OP specifically indicated that they can't declare the throw, because it is an overriden method.

Comment: In that case he could put the whole code into a try-catch block, throw the exception when needed and in the catch block call a method from a previously set listener

Comment: so that would not be an exception thrown, but rather a listener call. quite different.

Comment: side note: `MyOwnException` is not an `Exception` in this case.

Comment: Yep, my fault. I forgot the "extends Exception"